# Is there a difference between `= function()` and `= (select function())`?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `parent`:

```
create table parent
(
  identifier serial primary key,
  name text
);
```

Now I have the following two functions:

```
create or replace function test_a() returns integer
as $$
  insert into parent(name) values('testing') returning identifier;
$$ language sql;

create or replace function test_b() returns setof parent
as $$
  delete from parent where identifier = (test_a()) returning parent.*;
$$ language sql;
```

Now I do:

```
select * from test_b();
```

This does not return any rows. This makes sense, the `delete` cannot see the row as inserted by the `insert`, as this row was just inserted and therefore not in snapshot as defined when the `select * from test_b()` query was executed.

Following this logic, the row should be in the table. So let's examine `parent`:

```
select * from parent;
```

This does not return any rows. I don't get this. Why is this? If my reasoning was flawed (can you explain why), why did `select * from test_b()` then not return the row? This seems like a contradictio in terminis.

**update**

If I have the following two functions, it's completely different:

```
create or replace function test_a() returns integer
as $$
  insert into parent(name) values('testing') returning identifier;
$$ language sql;

create or replace function test_b() returns setof parent
as $$
  delete from parent where identifier = (select test_a()) returning parent.*;
$$ language sql;
```

Note that `(select test_a())` is the only difference here.

Now `select * from test_b()` still does not return rows, but the subsequent `select * from parent` returns the one row we inserted. This makes sense according to my reasoning regarding the snapshot scope above.

Is there a difference between `= (test_a())` and `= (select test_a())`?

Comment: Interesting. I can't answer this, I would have always expected using the function name without a SELECT would be the same, but take a look at the query plans: 

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM parent WHERE identifier = test_a();`:
`Seq Scan on parent  (cost=0.00..332.88 rows=1 width=36)
  Filter: (identifier = test_a())`;

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM parent WHERE identifier = (SELECT test_a());`:
`Index Scan using parent_pkey on parent  (cost=0.41..8.43 rows=1 width=36)
  Index Cond: (identifier = $0)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hesitate to post this as an answer as I don't really know the answer to your question, and I'm sure someone else will be able to explain exactly why this is so. But I found it very interesting so I had a little play with it and this is what I've found.

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM parent WHERE identifier = test_a();`

`Seq Scan on parent  (cost=0.00..26.20 rows=1 width=12)
  Filter: (identifier = test_a())`

vs

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM parent WHERE identifier = (SELECT test_a());`

`Seq Scan on parent  (cost=0.26..2.46 rows=1 width=12)
  Filter: (identifier = $0)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0)`

(I've dropped the PK)

The `(SELECT test_a())` is a subquery. It is resolved once, up front, and its result is used in the subsequent sequential scan of the other records.

When you say `identifier = test_a()`, because the test_a() function is volatile, it will be executed for every record read in the sequential scan. (If the function was immutable, the call to test_1a() would be substituted with the immutable function's value).

Now try this:

1. truncate parent
2. Run `SELECT * FROM test_b()` a few times
3. `SELECT * FROM parent` - you'll find nothing has been created.
4. `SELECT * FROM test_a()` - just to create a single record
5. Run `SELECT * FROM test_b()` a few times
6. `SELECT * FROM parent` - you should see not only do you now have a record for every time you ran the query in step 5, but quite a few more as well.

My interpretation: when you run test_b() when there's no data, the point at which test_a() would be called is never reached - because it's not resolved ahead of time, and instead is resolved when doing the test for each record. As there are no records, test_a() is never called. Now you create a single record, then call test_b() again. This time the single record is compared against the result of a call to test_a(). Run it again, and both records are compared against the result of a call to test_a() (so it's called twice, creating two more records). Run it a few more times, and the number of records in the table doubles each time.

As stated earlier, the `(SELECT test_a())` version, since it uses a subquery, resolves the value ahead of time. So when you call test_b(), it first calls test_a(), creating a record, even if there's no existing record in `parent` to read yet. Hence that version can create a record in an empty table, whereas the other version won't create any records if none exist.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you so much. It will take some time to digest, so my feedback might be slow, but I already want to say that I really appreciate your time.

Comment: No problem, hopefully it helps clarify what's going on. It actually became much clearer to me what was happening as I wrote it. I should probably also make clear that the functions in the steps I list above use the first version of your functions, not the second.

Comment: It makes so much sense now. The difference is very clear. I absolutely did not think about the fact that `select test_a()` is seen as a sub-query and could be evaluated upfront, as you explained; while `test_a()` is evaluated for each row, because it is a `volatile` function.